# Xamarin Android load local html file with routing

Tags: c#, android, html, xamarin.android, android-webview

How can I load local html file with routing in `Android Webview`?
The url looks like this:

```
file:///android_asset/Content/index.html/#/first-view
file:///android_asset/Content/index.html/#/second-view
```

I tried with this code but it's not working:

```
AppWebView.LoadUrl("file:///android_asset/Content/index.html/#/first-view");
```

Comment: Hey dude, did you ever figure this out?